# OSX Lion 10.7.1 - Safari, Textedit or Stickies in separate Mission Control Desktops

Tags: macos, mission-control

I have various Safari windows, TextEdit docs, and Stickies notes that relate to different things (e.g. work, home). I want to split these across two Mission Control desktops depending on what they are for. On Mission Control, I can't seem to drag these separate windows or even whole apps (collection of windows via the icon) into a desktop - the drag action works, the plus square appears, but the item then just springs back. Same for hovering it at edge of screen.

Update: these apps had "Assign to All" set - changing to "Assign to None" via Dock did the trick :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the item you're trying to move springs back then it's most likely already on the space / desktop you're trying to move it to.

You can also try moving something to another desktop in ways other than Mission Control:

- Let's say you already setup two spaces, and you want something from
  space one onto space two; Just drag the window of whatever it is to
  the edge of the screen and hold it there until it moves over to the
  other space.
- Another way you can do this is to simply open whatever application or
  file you want in that particular space.

Apps are automatically assigned to the Desktop / Space where they are launched for the very first time. You change this by <kbd>Control</kbd> clicking the apps icon in the
   dock, and assign to None.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about assign to None - setting this did what I wanted.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. ;-)